# Jest TypeError: function not found

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, jestjs

I am trying to run a test with jest, except it cannot find my function. I am exporting multiple functions from one file using `module.exports = {}`.

Here is my test file:

```
const queries = ('../config/queries');

test('Check Activation Code. -- checkActivationCode(test@gmail.com, 0123456789) ',  () => {
  let email = 'test%40gmail.com';
  let code = 1234567890;
  let result = "";

  queries.checkActivationCode(email, code, function(error, result) {
    if (error) result = false;
    else result = true;
  });
  expect(result).toBe(true);
});
```

My file structure is as follows, `/config/queries/index.js`, I am able to access the functions in my other files just fine.

Here is my queries/index.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  checkActivationCode: function(email, code, callback) {
    pool.getConnection(function(error, connection) {
      connection.query('SELECT code FROM confirmation WHERE email = ?', [email.toLowerCase()], function(error, results) {
        if (error) callback(error);
        try {
          if (results[0].code === code) {
            callback(null, true);
          } else {
            callback(null, false);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          callback(null, false);
        }
      });
      connection.release();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Is queries defined in your test file?

Comment: @BenceGedai Thanks! I forgot to require my import. `const queries = require('../config/queries');`

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to require my queries.

`const queries = ('../config/queries');`
to
`const queries = require('../config/queries');`

Simple typo. Thanks @BenceGedai for catching that.